Multiplicity of Cartier divisor
If $A$ is a ring, the length $length(M)$ of a module $M$ over $A$ is defined to be the sup of the $n$ such that their exists a chain $M_{0} := 0 \subset M_{1} ... \subset M_{n} =: M$ with $M_{i+1}/M_{i}$ simple (i.e. non zero and without any non trivial sub-module).
For a locally noetherian scheme $X$, and $x$ a point of codimension $1$, we define for any regular element $f \in \mathcal{O}_{X, x},$ $mult_{x}(f) := length(\mathcal{O}_{X, x}/f)$ which induces a group morphism $mult_{x} : Frac(\mathcal{O}_{X, x})^{*}/\mathcal{O}_{X, x}^{*} \mapsto \mathbb{Z}$ (here, $Frac$ denotes the total ring of fraction).
We have the notion of Cartier divisor (I will use the notation expose, e.g., page $256$ of the Liu's book ). Let $D$ be such a divisor. We can then define for $x \in X$ a point of codimension $1$, $mult_{x}(D)$.
Question : why is there (locally) only a finite number of point $x \in X$ of codimension $1$ such that $mult_{x}(D) \neq 0$ ?
